# Extending session lifetime doesn't work in PHP

Tags: php, session, lifetime

I'm trying to extend session lifetime but the session ends after closing the browser in an hour though the session cookie didn't expire. Using firebug the session should end after a week but the session ends after closing the browser here's the code

```
$lifetime=604800;
session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
session_start();
ini_set('session.cookie_lifetime',604800);
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',604800);
```

The question now is how to extend the real session lifetime so it doesn't end before the desired date?

Comment: there is no sense in calling `ini_set` after `session_start`, anyway you have session_set_cookie_params which should work, can you provide network trace with actual http cookie header?

Comment: actually first comment http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php should solve your problem

Comment: I've used the first comment code and the problem wasn't solved. session lifetime in firebug ends next week but real session has ended @Lashane

Comment: how did you determine that session ended?

Comment: I got logged out @Lashane

Comment: but cookie with the same session id is sent? maybe you have other process/module which logs you out?

Comment: I login then close the browser open it again after an hour and echo the session the result is undefined index SESSION_NAME

Comment: headers: http://goo.gl/CSXJyE

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92424/discussion-between-php-user-and-lashane).